# How can we display different content on same page?

Tags: php, mysql

My PHP code for the genres link:

```
<?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser ='root';
    $dbpass = '';    
    $dbname = 'moviefone';
    $con = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser, $dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);    

    // Check connection    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){      
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .  mysqli_connect_error();    
    }    

    if (isset($_GET['genre'])){
        switch ($_GET['genre']){    
            case 'action':    
                break;    
            case 'art_and_experimental':    
                break;    
            case 'comedy':   
                break;    
            //etc    
        }    
    }    

    $resultcat=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE lang='hindi'");    
    $info=array();    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){ 
        $info[]=$row;    
    }     
?>
```

When I am in my www.example.com/movies page it displays all the results from movie, but I want to filter the result when users click on the genres link it should display all result from the hindi movie filter by genres on the same page.

Here is my html genres nav:

```
        <ul class="snav">    
            <li><a href="?genre=action">Action</a></li>    
            <li><a href="?genre=art_and_experimental">Art and Experimental</a></li>    
            <li><a href="?genre=comedy">Comedy</a></li>    
            <li><a href="?genre=crime_and_mystery">Crime and Mystery</a></li>    
        </ul>    
    </li>    
</ul>
```

Here I want the fetched content to be displayed on:

```
<div class="sub-column1">    
    <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo $info[0]['images'];?>" class="new-img2" /></a>    
    <a href="#" class="img_titles">chennai express</a>    
</div>
```

I cannot get it working. what am i suppose to do?

Comment: This is so unreadable... Can you please try to format your code?

Comment: ok am trying @qwertynl

Comment: why down vote? is this wrong question ?

Comment: What do you expect, you didn't even put any effort into asking the question so that it's understandable. You just posted an unformatted code and expected to get an answer.

Comment: actually i first posted a formatted question.but it was showing need 4 space for each line of code.i am new in stack so i actually don't how to write correctly.

Comment: I and afuzzyllama has posted an edit to your problem, so that's over with. Also, you should use PDO instead of mysql_* as it's a deprecated method.

Comment: Hey @Sunny, are you saying you want to be able to select the lang as well as the genre? Also, just so you know, you can't use mysql and mysqli functions together.

Comment: @AttisBarros I agree that PDO is better, cleaner and safer; however, there is nothing wrong with using mysqli functionality.

Comment: @RossWilson what i am trying to do is that when i am on the movies page it display all genres movies.but in the movie page there is  genre list .when user click on a specific genre it should not display all genres movie but it should display the movies with specific genre user selected .

Comment: Where does `lang='hindi'` come in to it?

Comment: @RossWilson actually separated the movies with language.so i posted the query of hindi movies page that is why  lang='HINDI'.

Comment: So, you don't need help with the lang bit then? Also, I assume you have a `genre` field in your database table?

Comment: @RossWilson yes i have a genre field in my database table.and also need help with lang!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_GET['genre'])){

    $genre = $_GET['genre'];

    $resultcat=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies WHERE genre='$genre'"); 

} else {
    $resultcat=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM movies"); 
}
    $info=array();    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultcat)){ 
        $info[]=$row;    
    }
```

Comment: well@Rosswilson if i remove the ul tag the drop down menu will collapsed.so you think i should just remove the ul ??

Comment: and @RossWillson it showing undefined variable info.why ?

Comment: If the undefined variable is $data change it to `$resultcat` as mysql_fetch_assoc needs to be passed the query variable.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: info in C:\wamp\www\test\website3\hindi.php on line 106 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0004689752{main}( )..\hindi.php:0 " class="new-img2" />

Comment: $info is now being set inside the if statement, so if `genre` and `lang` are not passed in the url then `$info` is not getting set. You need to either have some other wrap your `sub_column1` div in an if statemet with the condition `isset($info)`

Comment: hey@RossWillson i have the dropdown list in my hindi.php page.and i have genre page ok.what if i click on the action it should redirect me to the page where action=genre. i mean something like this ex:`www.ex.com/hindi.php`i am in now. when i click on genre it should look like this www.ex.com/hindi.php/action.i want to do this.

Comment: So, you didn't need to select the language at all?!? To be fair, you've kind of lost me now, dude. Have a look at this http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLfdtiltiRHWEbLm0ErHe7HgEOVIO26R_o I think will help you a lot :)

Comment: i need the language to be able to fetch hindi movies from db to display on `hindi.php` page.and i need to get the genres of hindi movies to be able to separate hindi movies into different genres.in `hindi.php` i fetching only language.but in `hindi.php/geners` page i am fetching `language and genres` both.(http://www.moviefone.com/movie-genre) something like this.i think you may understand it now .the drop down bar is same as on the link.

Comment: In that case I'll just change my answer to apply only to the hindi page. One sec..

Comment: Do you want it to display all (hindi) movies if genre isn't set?

Comment: can you please check the link before you edit. i think it will be help full for you to understand me.

Comment: yess i want to display all movies if genre is't set. and how will i display when genre is set ? but without form tag is it possible ?

Comment: Yeah, change it to how you had it originally and I'll change my answer.

Comment: okay @ Ross i am doing it.

Comment: its working perfectly .damn so much time.Thanks a lot man for your time and work.thanks :)

Comment: No worries, dude. Have a look at that youtube channel, it helped me out a lot when I first started.

Comment: how can i get number of result during the above query.not the number of rows .i want to get the number of results.

Comment: The number of rows would be the number of results... What do you need it for?

Comment: i will be needing this for displaying how many movies or videos have been found that is matching keyword a.i have implemented the search i just can't figure out how to count them.i was using mysql_num_rows but its to return the number of rows

Comment: I really don't know why the number of rows wouldn't be what you're looking for, unless you have the movies listed more than once in your db. You should look into mysql `COUNT` or `SUM()`. Also, I'm happy to help but you should really create a new question for this.